# Detect individual SYN or FIN packets

Tags: vb.net

Can I send and detect individual SYN or FIN packets using VB.NET Sockets or any other process in VB.NET?

Comment: Of course not.  That orange number under your name discourages people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you should be asking yourself is "why do I think I need to do this?"  I strongly suspect that whatever you're trying to do, there's a better way to do it.  What you're asking is to be able to manipulate the TCP state machine, and that's not something to be undertaken lightly, nor is it something that really should be permitted at such a high level.  Consider rethinking the situation.

Comment: @Chris, If a socket is in the middle of sending data to a server and the connection gets interrupted. The socket client knows that the data never made it to the server, but the server netstat maybe in established or Fin wait mode. I was thinking that if i was able to detect that the server netstat is in one of the two mode i can send a command to reset the server back to listen and try to send the data again.

Comment: @Mcdevitt, you should leave that up to the network stack.  You don't know what lower-level protocols are doing with your data.

Comment: @mcdevitt: how exactly does the client know that the data never made it to the server?  Even the client TCP doesn't know until it explicitly receives an ACK from the server indicating the last sequence number received on the stream.  As @brad says, leave this stuff up to the network stack.

Comment: @mcdevitt: In terms of resetting the server back to listen...does your server not accept connections even while still listening?  While I have written TCP servers that do not continue to listen once a connection was accepted, that was purely an academic exercise rather than a good design.

Comment: @Chris the Socket Server will not accept a new connection if the Client is sending from a new port. And because of the the network interruption the OS will give that client a new port each time there is a network problem.

Comment: This sounds more and more like a bad design.  However, that notwithstanding, why can't you bind to the same port on the client side every time?  After our network interruption, close the socket on the client side, bind to the One True Port, and perform a new connection attempt. That would send a new SYN with a new sequence number, which the server would recognize as out of sequence and send an RST to the client, i.e., reset the connection.  The client would then have to reattempt a connection, but it should work then.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that if you want to go down to this low of a level, you are going to need a packet capture driver.

Winpcap is commonly used for this on Windows.  There is at least one .NET wrapper for it.  See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dotnetwinpcap.aspx